# What makes Android GUI framework

Tags: android, user-interface

Java is used to bring up gui components like View and Widgets. Official site say they dont include AWT/Swing as a part of their java bundle, then what implementation (native-wrapper if any?) they have in place? Also is it possible to create user interface from scratch for android apps without extending any View class?

Comment: Basically I wanted to know what is analogues in android for WIN32-GDI (in windows) or X Windows system (in linux), it seems like Skia is the answer

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom UI toolkit unrelated to AWT or Swing.

You can create custom subclasses of the View class to draw whatever custom components you would like, but most of the time you can set attributes on the existing components to change the way they're drawn (like setting the drawables for a button).

Comment: would you say that by extending View class I can create ui components of any complexity that android allows?

Comment: Think about composing existing Views in a ViewGroup first. You can do pretty much anything you want in a View - you're drawing via onDraw and listening for user interaction via listeners. But seriously look at tweaking existing View types first - they handle user interaction in a very consistent manner and deal with a lot of smaller details (such as saving data when the device is rotated) for you.

Comment: Views are quite logical to extend but many prebuilt Classes will not have much opening to modify their behaviour. If i am not wrong WebView class do not extend any View but invokes native webkit for all kind of jobs!